# Insert multiple rows selected from another table and return ID of first inserted row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, insert

I am successfully inserting multiple rows selected from another table using this query:

```
INSERT INTO `products`(`description`, `number`)
    SELECT `article_description`, `article_number`
    FROM articles
```

Need some help as I now would like to:

1) Be able to return the value of the first ID (so let's say `product_id`) inserted. So the first row inserted in that multiple `INSERT`.

2) If 1) is not possible then perhaps return the value of the `last row inserted`.

Few questions:
 - How should I modify my query?
 - Or which action should I take once this `INSERT` is completed?
 - Should I use `mysqli_insert_id()`?

Comment: last_insert_id will do the last one

Comment: It's not necessary to repeat tags in the title, nor arbitrarily CAPITALIZE words.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Do you want to know the ID of all inserted records? Without some kind of back-tracking system this isn't really practical, MySQL doesn't support `RETURNING` like some other databases do. You're stuck inserting them as singles and keeping track of the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` results.

Comment: Are you prepared to use an insert trigger? You could use an insert trigger to store the first insert into a log table that you could then interrogate.

Comment: Strawberry what if someone else does an insert between when my insert query is done and when last_insert_id executes? Are we sure last_insert_id is really correspond to the last ones of the multiple insert?